# Pip missing in python script

Tags: python, pip, python-3.8

I checked that I am using python 3.8.5 on my windows 10. I'm trying to install a package with pip but the terminal tells me '[pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.]

I am using Python version 3.8.5 and I understand python version 3.4 and above have pip pre-installed,
I tried setting environment variables and all other alternative solution like I tried python -m pip --version it showed me error... still I am not able to solve it. Then I noticed pip.exe file missing from python/scripts module, so what can I do next.... Does I have to install it manually??

Comment: Try `python -v` on cmd, if it's also giving an error, then you have installed python incorrectly

Comment: Uninstall your python and reinstall it by selecting on `Add Python Path to Environment Variables` u will get your error solved

Comment: pip is already installed if you are using Python 2 >=2.7.9 or Python 3 >=3.4 downloaded from python.org so it would be best to check if you have installed python correctly as others suggested

Comment: Aside: Always use `python -m pip` and even more generally `path/to/pythonX.Y -m pip ...`. You should not care too much about `pip.exe` being there or not, and even about python and pip being on the `PATH` environment variable or not. -- https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/

Answer (score 1):

pip doesn't work unless you have added python to path.

There are two methods to add python to path:

1. Reinstall python and make sure to check the box that says "Add Python To Path"
2. https://datatofish.com/add-python-to-windows-path/

Comment: I  have added path in environment variable still it is not solving error

Comment: why you give a link man just *** add Script to path: D:\python\Scripts